# Type "character set" has no member "utf8"

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8

the code here goes to the credit of Jameson Quave.

URL: www.jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-apps-using-swift-tutorial-part-2/

I have attempted to edit it to work with Swift 3. The issue I am having is the error message for this line:

```
if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlquery)
```

(it states `.utf8` in the code)

I am unsure as to what I need to place in the `.urlquery` section

The error code I get is the title. I have tried to google for answers and found `String.Encoding.utf8` which also did not work. The original code had `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var appsViewTable: UITableView!
    var tableData = []

    func searchItunesFor(searchTerm: String) {
        //The iTunes API wants multiple terms seperated by + symbols, so replace spaces with + signs
        let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: nil)

        //Now escape anything else that isn't URL-friendly
        if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .utf8) {
            let urlPath = "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=software"
            let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                printIn("Task completed")
                if(error != nil) {
                    // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
                    printIn(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                var err: NSError?
                if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectiveWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
                    if(err != nil) {
                        // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                        printIn("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.tableData = results
                            self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                }
            })

        // The task if just an object with all these properties set
        // In order to actually make the web request, we need to "resume"
        task.resume()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `.urlQueryAllowed`:

```
escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

The *withAllowedCharacters* expects a character set that defines all the characters that do not need escaping. It's not related to the text encoding (such as UTF-8).